# How to prevent printing the entire response body in Cypress Test Body?

Tags: cypress, assertion

I'm looping the variable called `element` through a pretty huge list of ids, and when index is around 500-1000 Cypress runner is slowing down because of enormous data printed in Test Body. My assertion looks like that:

```
cy.get('@sku').should((response) => {
        expect(response.body).contain(element)
})
```

What can I do to prevent such a behavior?

[image]

Comment: Can you try passing `log: false` in `cy.get(‘@sku’,{log: false})` and see if you get the logs then.

Comment: @AlapanDas unfortunately, logs with huge response.body are still visible :l

Comment: @AlapanDas I think it's not possible to achieve that right now. Look at this thread: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/7693  but maybe I'm wrong...